# Vim gF should open file and jump to line

Tags: vim, file-io

I tried out `gF` and it seems to not behave like mentioned in `:help gF`

If cursor is positioned on an entry `x.c` and I type `gf` the file is opened.

If cursor is positioned on an entry `x.c:3` and I type `gF` I get `E447: Can't find file "x.c:3" in path`. Whereby :3 should tell vim to jump to line 3.

What do I miss?

Comment: Works as expected for me. Check if there isn't any mapping in gF with `:map gf`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Enter `:set isfname`

It'll show an OS dependent list of all characters considered being possibly part of a file name. On my system (Windows), the column `:` appears in the list.

```
isfname=@,48-57,/,\,.,-,_,+,,,#,$,%,{,},[,],:,@-@,!,~,=
```

Hence it won't be considered by gF as a separator between file name and line number. However if I add a space between them, the behaviour goes as documented.

Given how no sane person uses `:` in a file name, if you want to use `gF` on some compiler's output that says `file.c:120`, you can add this to your vimrc :

```
set isfname-=:
```

(mind the `-` before the `=`)

If ever one day you need to open a file that has a `:` in its name, you can always enter `:set isfname+=:` to restore the column as a valid file name character for the duration of that session.

Comment: If you have to edit a file with `:`, just select it in visual and `gf` instead